# same path occuring many times in xslt

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I am defining few variables and I have `select="-------"` in them. In those the first parts of the path are the same. Is there any way I can have some sort of a constant type of a thing defined so that I can use it without having to retype the same thing over and over again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you can use a variable

```
<xsl:variable name="foo" select="/a/b/foo"/>
<xsl:variable name="bar" select="$foo/bar"/>
<xsl:variable name="foobar" select="$foo/foobar"/>
```

instead of

```
<xsl:variable name="bar" select="/a/b/foo/bar"/>
<xsl:variable name="foobar" select="/a/b/foo/foobar"/>
```

But as you are already using variables that looks too obvious so maybe I am missing what the problem is.

Comment: yes this is correct. but what is the purpose of making it a variable? it is not varying.

Comment: The purpose is to save you from repeating the complexity of the selector (as well as any potential runtime cost). Granted, you're still repeating the identifier's name, but that's the less complicated of the alternatives. Although called variable, maybe "binding" is a better term for what XSL actually allows: variables that you cannot change. You might also hear this referred to as a "value."

Comment: Setinger, the `xsl:variable` element allows you to bind a value to an identifier. It is true that you can't change an `xsl:variable` but if you want to avoid to repeat e.g. `/a/b/foo` several times then using an `xsl:variable` is the XSLT way of doing that.